# "This is commentary on another post, NAA" doesn't make sense for lone self-answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, low-quality-posts

I was reviewing low quality posts today and I noticed that some of the messages are smart enough to change. When the post is a self answer, for example, it gives you the option to say that the answer should have been an edit. (I like this feature.)

So I was surprised when I realized that this is also an option on self-answers *when there are no other answers*:

> This is commentary on another post, not an answer
>
> “This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.”

Does it really make sense to have this as an option? Whose post? The answer and question are written by the same person.

The people who receive these messages are mostly new users with little experience on the site, so it would be even more confusing for them than it is for any of us.

I understand that this option makes sense for self-answers where there is another answer (assuming it's not another self-answer). But this wasn't the case.

We should change the wording or remove the option when there is only one author, who both asked and answered.

(Note that comments ≠ posts. It might make sense to have the option apply to posts and comments, not just posts. As it is currently written, it gives the wrong idea about comments, which are not supposed to be on the same importance level as posts.)

[image: Is this real?]

Comment: Many of those self-answers are replies to existing comments, so the wording should probably focus on that as a major part.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, in many cases they are. That's what I was trying to say in my last sentence. (Just note that the author from the screenshot DID know how to comment, as you would've seen if I included the question too.)

Comment: Another "post" isn't circumscripted to only answers, it could be the question or a comment itself that was *posted*.

Comment: @Braiam I think you missed what I said. Comments are not considered posts (according to the SO model and its database). And the other key fact here is that the author of the question is the same person who posted the answer. It is a bit bizarre to suggest you ask clarification from yourself.

Comment: "Comments are not considered posts" if we are going that way, comments are POSTed using POST to site/posts/id/comments. Forget about *technicallies*, anything that is addresses the content that isn't the question isn't an answer, doesn't matter whenever is the own author, a comment in the post or another answer..

Comment: @Braiam But this close reason can be used when the questions, all its comments (if any) and all the answer(s) were all written by the same person. I agree with you that this stuff is most certainly not an answer in a lot of cases, but I think that this wording is nonsensical under these conditions.

Answer (score 1):

How does number of other answers affect the fact that asker adds update of his question by posting it as an answer instead of edit? So yes, this option make sense.

Comment: I think you're thinking of something else. There's another option that says that the answer should have been an edit, but I think that is fine. The option I am talking about would lead the answerer to believe that they should have asked themselves for clarification.